# How to write Regex to replace some words and add "" if missing in JavaScript. Unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have to find some key strings and surrond them with quote if they are not:

```
`[aa,bb,cc, "aa","bb","cc"]`.replace(/[^"](aa|bb)[^"]/g, `"$1"`)
```

expected:

```
"["aa","bb",cc, "aa","bb","cc"]"
```

but I got this:

```
""aa""bb",cc, "aa","bb","cc"]"
```

What was happend with '[' and comma ','?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture `[^"]` too and use back reference while replacing, as you're not capturing them and replacing only the matched value with the captured group so you end up loosing the value matched by `[^"]`

```js
let final = `[aa,bb,cc "aa","bb","cc"]`.replace(/([^"])(aa|bb)(?!")/g, `$1"$2"`)

console.log(final)
```

Comment: Almost but wrong `"["aa",bb,cc, "aa","bb","cc"]"`. What about `bb`? Should be `"["aa","bb",cc, "aa","bb","cc"]"`

Comment: @MrHIDEn you can use lookahead instead, see the updated, if your environment support lookbehind then we can use that too

Comment: thank you, that is good. I could not solve that. There was missing comma after `cc` but any way your code works well. Thak you. Quick!! :)

Answer (score 0):

`[aa,bb,cc "aa","bb","cc"]`.replace(/([^"])(\w\w)(?!")/g, `$1"$2"`)

Comment: Question is to catch `aa` and `bb` only.

Comment: @MrHIDEn Ok. Thank you, I thought needed everything.